# How to print values in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

How to print values in Codeigniter?
I have following code:

```
<table>
<tr>
<?php 
foreach($assigned_qu[0] as $key => $qu){
?>
<td id="qtd4"><?php echo $key;?></td>
<?php
}
?>
</tr></table>
```

It gives:

```
<tr><td id="qtd4">ex1</td>
<td id="qtd4">ex2</td>
<td id="qtd4">ex3</td>
<td id="qtd4">ex4</td>
</tr>
```

I want print values like this:

```
<tr>  <td id="qtd4">ex1</td> /* how to print `<tr></tr>` tags? */
<td id="qtd4">ex2</td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td id="qtd4">ex3</td>
<td id="qtd4">ex4</td>  </tr>
```

How do print two `td` tags between `tr` tag

Comment: Yo want two columns?(two td tags between tr tag?)

Comment: yes. i want two td tags between tr tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this soltion :

```
<?php 
$cnt=0;
foreach($assigned_qu[0] as $key => $qu){
    if($cnt%2 == 0){
        echo "<tr>";
    }
?>
<td id="qtd4"><?php echo $key;?></td>

<?php
$cnt++;
if($cnt%2 == 0){
        echo "</tr>";
    }   
}
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php
    foreach ($assigned_qu as $qu):
        ?>

    <tr><td id="qtd4"><?php echo $qu->table_column_name;?></td></tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.i want two `td` tags between `tr` tag

Answer (score 0):

Here is the php code on how to display a table as per your question:

```
<table>
    <?php 
        foreach($assigned_qu[0] as $key => $qu){
            ?>
                <tr>
                    <td id="qtd4"><?php echo $key;?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php
        }
    ?>
</table>
```